# Defining a different symbol to be used as a sum-class symbol

Tags: symbols, subscripts, superscripts

If I'm interested in using an arbitrary symbol or character instead of the default sum-class symbols (such as `\int`, `\coprod`, etc), solely with the interest of preserving subscripts and superscripts above and below the symbol, how should I proceed?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 11):

Try `\DeclareMathOperator*{\foo}{...}`. You'll need to load the `amsmath` package. This makes `\foo` have "limit-style" subscripts and superscripts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\foo}{\maltese}

\begin{document}
\[
\foo_{i=3}^{6}(f^2(i))
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the symbol to be larger, then just writing `\Large\maltese` won't work. Instead, you could use:

```
\DeclareMathOperator*{\foo}{\text{\Large $\maltese$}}
```

[image]

Comment: there's already a `\bigoplus` that comes in the requisite two sizes, one for in-text, and one for display.  for large operators that aren't yet "available", the two-size convention should be observed, so either two different operaters should be defined, or a rather more complicated formulation using `\mathchoice` (in which sizes appropriate for use in sub/superscripts can also be provided).

Comment: Heh, that's true. I should really have chosen one of the gazillion other symbols available!

Comment: if you want to revise your answer, why don't you try `\maltese` (from `amsfonts`).  i'm pretty sure that comes in only one size.  i was going to suggest `\box<something>`, but noticed (in the comprehensive symbols list) that `\bigbox<something>` has actually been concocted for nearly all `<something>`s.

Comment: +1 Note also that for a one-off use one has the low-level `\( \mathop{\wr}\limits_{i=1}^n \)`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I've revised my answer as per your suggestion. Thanks `:-)`. Btw, what's the "proper" way to do this? I mean, how is `\Sigma` scaled to the right size and vertical position to make a summation symbol, for instance?

Comment: @ConcernedUndergraduate You're welcome `:-)`. If the answer has now solved your problem, please consider clicking the "tick mark" to mark it as accepted. And if not, do let us know.

Comment: @JohnWickerson -- `\Sigma` (and other large operator symbols) are present twice in what's called the "extension font", and "chained" from smaller to larger.  the "correct" one is chosen and positioned (centered vertically on the math axis) by the tex engine depending on the context: text, display, first-order script, second-order script (the last two are reduced in size from the text-size form; the first two are set at "true" size, modulo the actual size of the surrounding text, i.e., reduced for footnotes, enlarged for some titles).  this would make a good question itself -- ask it!

Comment: @barbarabeeton There's a question *[here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116506/how-are-big-operators-defined)* on which you might have an opinion...`:-)`.