# How are big operators defined?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, math-operators

I would like to create a new "big operator", by which I mean something like the Σ character used for summations.

[image]

I know about the `\DeclareMathOperator*` command, which creates an operator whose superscripts and subscripts are written directly above and below the operator. Here is an example of that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\foo}{\maltese}

\begin{document}
\[
\foo_{i=3}^{6}(f^2(i))
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I would like to make my operator "big". I tried this:

```
\DeclareMathOperator*{\foo}{\text{\Large $\maltese$}}
```

[image]

but that feels like a bit of a hack. Besides, the operator is too high, and needs moving down a tad to align it properly with its operand. So, what's the *proper* way to do this? How, for instance, is the `\sum` operator defined?

Comment: To answer your last question, `\show\sum` reveals that the sigma symbol is stored in `\mathchar"1350`.

Comment: Take also a look at the mathlarger command in the relsize package (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7462/how-to-make-math-symbols-bigger )

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The `scalerel` package allows you to scale a symbol to the size (and vertical positioning) of another symbol.  So in this case, I define `\foo` to scale `\maltese` to the size of `\sum`.  Thus, it piggybacks its sizing off the well defined behavior of `\sum`.

It wasn't clear to me if the questioner wanted to keep the maltese cross the same size in all operations.  However, if that is the case, I can redefine the `\foo` operator as `\barr` in order to keep the size equal to that of a `textstyle` summation sign.  The example below shows instances of `\foo` as well as `\barr` in both displaystyle and inline.

Edit: Use `scalerel` version 1.5 or later to ensure that `scalerel` captures the current math style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\foo}{\scalerel*{\maltese}{\sum}}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\barr}{\scalerel*{\maltese}{\textstyle\sum}}
\usepackage{scalerel}

\begin{document}
\[
\foo_{i=3}^{6}(f^2(i))
\]

This is inline: \(\foo_{i=3}^{6}(f^2(i)) \)

\[
\barr_{i=3}^{6}(f^2(i))
\]

This is inline: \(\barr_{i=3}^{6}(f^2(i)) \)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is useful for defining a symbol to represent the assembly operator on matrices in finite element analysis:
`\DeclareMathOperator*{\assembly}{\scalerel*{\mathsf{A}}{\sum}}`

Answer (score 44):

Operators such as `\sum` are not defined with `\DeclareMathOperator` that should be used (with or without a `*`) for “textual” operators.

The definition of `\sum` is

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sum}{\mathop}{largesymbols}{"50}
```

that becomes, internally,

```
\mathchardef\sum="1350
```

The macro `\DeclareMathOperator` uses `\mathop`, which has a strange property: if its argument turns out to be a single character, it will be raised or lowered so that it becomes centered with respect to the math axis (where fraction lines are typeset).

Since there is no “big version“ of `\maltese`, one has to resort to other methods for building a good symbol from it. Indeed, one of the math font properties is that some characters have instructions telling where to find “big versions” for it.

TeX has a workaround, which is called `\mathchoice`; so you can do it with something like:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand{\bigmaltese}{%
  \mathop{ % we want it to be an operator
    \mathchoice{\dobigmaltese\Large}
               {\dobigmaltese\large}
               {\dobigmaltese\normalsize}
               {\dobigmaltese\small}
    }\displaylimits % not necessary, but added for clarity
}

\newcommand{\dobigmaltese}[1]{%
  \vcenter{#1\kern.2ex\hbox{$\maltese$}\kern.2ex}}

\begin{document}
Here's in text, $\bigmaltese_{i=1}^n x_i$, next in display
\[
\bigmaltese_{i=1}^n x_i
\]
\end{document}
```

We define for each style what we want. The `\dobigmaltese` command builds a box centered with respect to the formula axis. I've added some room above and below. This won't change sizes when the overall font size changes; a slightly different method would be necessary.

[image]

Comment: There's a better answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23432/4427

Answer (score 14):

If you execute

```
tftopl cmex10.tfm > cmex10.pl
```

and look at character octal 120 ( = hex 50) you see

```
(CHARACTER O 120
   (CHARWD R 1.055559)
   (CHARDP R 1.000013)
   (NEXTLARGER O 130)
   )
```

which tells you (or at least, tells TeX) that there is a larger version of the character at position octal 130.

Comment: David, how do you know that character octal 120 corresponds to uppercase sigma?

Comment: @Jubobs because you helpfully told me that in your comment, so it saved me looking it up:-) the last two (hex) digits of the mathchar you quoted are 50. Note that this is a summation sign not a sigma.