# A large "#" symbol

Tags: symbols

I´m trying to typeset a large # symbol. I tried

`\newcommand*{\con}{\scalebox{1.5}{\ensuremath{\#}}}`

but i would also like to add subscripts in math mode so that they appear underneath the symbol. I would like to have the symbol that has the same relationship to # as, say, `\bigoplus` has to `oplus`. Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/116506/15925

Comment: @AndrewSwann Thanks! This is what I was looking for. You may close the question as a duplicate now... sorry I didn´t spot it myself.