# Displaystyle/limits for custom operators

Tags: math-mode

I want to write this:

```
$ {\text{\huge N}}\limits_{i<k} $
```

and have it produce output comparable to this:

```
$ \sum\limits_{i<k} $
```

That is, I want a sum with limits underneath it, but I want it with a capital nu instead of a capital sigma. My proposed approach doesn't work though. How does one get \limits on a custom operator?

Comment: Could this help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116506/how-are-big-operators-defined/116538#116538?  Maybe a duplicate?  Just substitute `N` for `\maltese`.

Comment: Exactly, thanks. What should I have searched for?

Comment: Well "Big Operator" would have found it.  But I had the advantage, because I know the author of that answer quite well ;^)