# Writing X as a symbol with limits

Tags: symbols

I wish to write X as product like `$X_{n=1}^k$`. How to write it? For example, we write `$\sum \limits _{n=1}^k$`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I am not sure if I get you right. Please explain a bit more, what you want to achieve here. If necessary draw a little picture and post it. Do you want to get a new symbol which is used like `\prod \limits` but looks like a big X?

Comment: I wish to write \times but a bit larger with limits.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: There are several related posts: http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=bigtimes

Answer (score 12):

## Classical TeX

Both `MnSymbol` and `mathabx` provides the symbol `\bigtimes`. However both packages also change the math symbols, but it is also possible to only get `\bigtimes`.

### `MnSymbol`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\begin{document}
\[
  \bigtimes_{n=1}^k
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result MnSybmol]

Version without package `MnSymbol` by using the relevant code from the package only:

```
\documentclass{article}

% MnSymbol

\usepackage{amsmath}% provides \DOTSB and \slimits@
\makeatletter
\DeclareFontFamily{U}  {MnSymbolF}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{symbolsMN}{U}{MnSymbolF}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{symbolsMN}{bold}{U}{MnSymbolF}{b}{n}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolF}{m}{n}{
    <-6>  MnSymbolF5
   <6-7>  MnSymbolF6
   <7-8>  MnSymbolF7
   <8-9>  MnSymbolF8
   <9-10> MnSymbolF9
  <10-12> MnSymbolF10
  <12->   MnSymbolF12}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolF}{b}{n}{
    <-6>  MnSymbolF-Bold5
   <6-7>  MnSymbolF-Bold6
   <7-8>  MnSymbolF-Bold7
   <8-9>  MnSymbolF-Bold8
   <9-10> MnSymbolF-Bold9
  <10-12> MnSymbolF-Bold10
  <12->   MnSymbolF-Bold12}{}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\tbigtimes}{\mathop}{symbolsMN}{2}
\newcommand*{\bigtimes}{%
  \DOTSB
  \tbigtimes
  \slimits@ 
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
  \bigtimes_{n=1}^k
\]
\end{document}
```

### `mathabx`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathabx}

\begin{document}
\[
  \bigtimes_{n=1}^k
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result mathabx]

Without package:

```
\documentclass{article}

% mathabx

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{
      <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10>
      <10.95> <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88>
      mathx10
      }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bigtimes}{1}{mathx}{"91}

\begin{document}
\[
  \bigtimes_{n=1}^k
\]
\end{document}
```

## LuaTeX/XeTeX with `unicode-math`

As David Carlisle has written in his [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/202531/16967), the symbol is a Unicode symbol:

```
U+2A09 n-ary times operator
```

It can be used directly or via command `\bigtimes` with package `unicode-math` and TeX engines, which support OpenType fonts (LuaTeX, XeTeX).

Example with different fonts:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
  \newcommand*{\test}[1]{%
    \setmathfont{#1.otf}%
    \[
      \bigtimes_{n=1}^k\quad \mbox{\footnotesize(#1)}%
    \]%
  }
  \test{latinmodern-math}
  \test{Asana-Math}
  \test{xits-math}
  \test{texgyrebonum-math}
  \test{texgyrepagella-math}
  \test{texgyreschola-math}
  \test{texgyretermes-math}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result unicode-math]

Comment: aha, I've updated my answer to refer to yours for classic TeX:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am referencing back and have added a full example with differernt fonts.

Answer (score 7):

Is this what you mean?  Here are two variants, using answer from [How are big operators defined?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116506/how-are-big-operators-defined/116538#116538)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\foo}{\scalerel*{\times}{\sum}}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\barr}{\scalerel*{\times}{\textstyle\sum}}
\usepackage{scalerel}

\begin{document}
\[
\foo_{i=3}^{6}(f^2(i))
\]

This is inline: \(\foo_{i=3}^{6}(f^2(i)) \)

\[
\barr_{i=3}^{6}(f^2(i))
\]

This is inline: \(\barr_{i=3}^{6}(f^2(i)) \)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It,s not like "\times". It is like "X". I want to write like "\times" with limits.

Comment: @hamed Please see revision

Comment: The spacing isn't right here; there's too much horizontal space around the symbol (e.g. look at the location of the arguments when you call the command inline; there's a big space separating the X from the subscript "i=3" and the superscript 6.).

Comment: To fix the spacing issue, this modification of your answer works decently well: \DeclareMathOperator*{\bigtimes}{\scalerel*{\hspace{-0.09em}\times\hspace{-0.09em}}{\sum}}

Comment: Thank you @xFioraMstr18.  It is true that with the scale, the sidebearing is also scaled, which is normally not called for.  Removing some via negative kern seems appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

Unicode has this symbol as U+2A09 (⨉) so if you are using a unicode engine (xetex or luatex) you can use that symbol directly or use `\bigtimes` with `unicode-math` package. See Heiko's answer to access fonts for classic TeX that have this symbol..