# Math operator always in textstyle

Tags: spacing, math-operators

I would like to define a macro that expands to the same symbol as `\sum` but using the inline style (`\textstyle`) even when used in a displayed environment.

Here's what I got:

```
\newcommand{\Alt}{\@ifstar{\sum}{{\textstyle\sum}}}
```

the starred version allows me to selectively enable displaystyle in exceptional situations. This is not a strong requirement however.

If I was not wrapping this in a macro I would have accomplished this by doing

```
bla {\textstyle \sum_a^b bla} bla
```

I am slightly uncomfortable with wrapping `\sum` in a group in the macro definition, only to limit the scope of `\textstyle`.

My question is: are there situations where spacing can be broken by the extra group around `\sum`?

Comment: Hi! Would you please care to show a formula where you consider it better to use the smaller symbol?

Comment: @tohecz I am using the `\sum` operator as an indexed form of "choice" in process algebra, not for "numerical" formulae.

Comment: you can use: `\DeclareMathOperator*{\barr}{\textstyle\sum}` to retain the smaller size.  But limits will change position for display and text style.  Is that OK?

Comment: @Bordaigorl Isn't then `\Sigma` what you look for?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes is `\DeclareMathOperator` going to set `\textstyle` for everything following `\barr` as well?

Comment: @tohecz `\mathrm{\Sigma}` is not the same as `\textstyle\sum`!

Comment: No, it will not set the remaining expression in `textstyle`.  See `\barr` in my answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116506/how-are-big-operators-defined/116538#116538 for comparison.  If you add `\frac{1}{2}` after a use of `\barr` in display environment, it will not be in `\textstyle`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes it's a good suggestion and a nice alternative to consider. However I would prefer to get always the same positioning of limits

Comment: Perhaps something like `\mathord{\textstyle\sum}_{i=3}^6` might be something that could be used, though the surrounding spaces are not quite correct...

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Is my tentative solution giving wrong spacings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on comment discussion, I had suggested something similar to the answer at [How are big operators defined?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116506/how-are-big-operators-defined/116538#116538), in the form of `\DeclareMathOperator*{\barr}{\textstyle\sum}`.  However, that approach still places displaystyle limits above and below the summation (ex. 1).  Nonetheless, we know that the spacing provided by `\barr` in textstyle (ex. 2) is the proper spacing the OP seeks.

I was able to recreate that spacing and sub/superscript placement in ex. 3-5, using different approaches.  Ex. 3 tricks the result in displaystyle by using a `\mathord` instead of a `\mathop`, but of course, the pre- and post- spacing need adjustment to match the proper (ex. 2) spacing.

Ex. 4 and 5 are variations on the OP's proposed approach.  In ex. 4, I add pre- and post- material inside his braces.  However, depending on the nature of the material, this approach may not be available for use.

Ex. 5 is the OP's approach, except that thin spaces have been added, since the braces remove the ability of the sum's `\mathop`edness to extend its reach outside of the braces.

This in fact answer's the OP's question of "are there situations where spacing can be broken by the extra group around `\sum`?", because without the thin spaces in ex. 5, the spacing of the OP's approach will not be correct.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\barr}{\textstyle\sum}
\begin{document}
\centering
\verb|\barr| in \verb|\displaystyle|:
\[
A\barr_{i=3}^{6}B
\]

\verb|\barr| in \verb|\textstyle|:

\medskip inline: \(A A\barr_{i=3}^{6}B B\)

\verb|\mathord| with thin spaces added
\[
A A\,\mathord{\textstyle\sum}_{i=3}^6\, B B
\]

OP's original approach \textit{if} pre- and post- content embraced
\[
A {A \textstyle \sum_{i=3}^6 B} B
\]

OP's original approach, with no embraced pre- and post- content, but thin spaces added

\[
A A {\,\textstyle \sum_{i=3}^6\,} B B
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent answer! So is there any way in your opinion I can avoid blocking `\mathop` and still limit the change to textstyle to the symbol?

Comment: @Bordaigorl  I'm sorry, but no obvious way around the manual correction jumps out at me, but ex. 5 or even `{{}\textstyle \sum_{i=3}^6{}}` might give you what you want.

Comment: I am accepting your answer since it shows when the spacing can be wrong, which was my initial concern. @egreg's answer is also very helpful for a possible fix

Answer (score 3):

You may want to have an abstract approach to this; we can exploit the fact that `amsmath` changes all operator names taking limits in a uniform way, by adding `@` at the end of the name to mean the symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newtoggle{reducedop}
\newcommand{\reduceoperatorsize}[1]{%
  \csletcs{#1saved}{#1}%
  \csletcs{#1@saved}{#1@}%
  \@namedef{#1}{%
    \@ifstar
      {\togglefalse{reducedop}\@nameuse{#1saved}}%
      {\toggletrue{reducedop}\@nameuse{#1saved}}%
  }
  \@namedef{#1@}{%
    \iftoggle{reducedop}
      {\reduced@operator{#1}}
      {\@nameuse{#1@saved}}
  }%
}
\newcommand{\reduced@operator}[1]{%
  \mathop{\mathpalette\reduced@operator@i{#1}\relax}%
}
\newcommand\reduced@operator@i[2]{%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle\textstyle\else#1\fi
  \csname #2@saved\endcsname
}
\makeatother

\reduceoperatorsize{sum}

\begin{document}
$\sum*_{k=1}^n$\quad$\sum_{k=1}^n$\quad$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n$
\[
\sum*_{k=1}^n\quad\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}
\]
\end{document}
```

The first line is meant to show that the usual behavior is respected.

[image]

The `amsmath` package redefines `\sum` with

```
\let\sum@\sum
\def\sum{\DOTSB\sum@\slimits@}
```

and does the same for `\coprod`, `\bigvee`, `\bigwedge`, `\biguplus`, `\bigcap`, `\bigcup`, `\prod`, `\bigotimes`, `\bigoplus`, `\bigodot` and `\bigsqcup`. This makes the symbols “dots aware” and respecting the `sumlimits` or `nosumlimits` option because of

```
\DeclareOption{sumlimits}{\let\slimits@\displaylimits}
\DeclareOption{nosumlimits}{\let\slimits@\nolimits}
```

Based on this, I redefine `\sum` to be

```
\togglefalse{reducedop}\sumsaved
```

if `\sum*` is found and

```
\toggletrue{reducedop}\sumsaved
```

otherwise. Here `\sumsaved` is the same as `\sum` as defined in `amsmath`. Then I redefine `\sum@` to do `\sum@saved` if the toggle is set to false, where `\sum@saved` is the same as the original `\sum@`. If the toggle is set to true, instead, `\mathop{\mathpalette\reduced@operator@i{sum}}` is executed. Within `\mathpalette` I check the style: if it is `\displaystyle`, I use `\textstyle`, otherwise the current style and typeset `\sum@saved`. The surrounding `\mathop` is followed by `\slimits@` as before.

Comment: this does corresponds more closely to what I wanted to achieve. It's still looking like black magic, I'll read it more carefully later! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but I was reading it today. What I use is this:

```
\newcommand{\sumt}[2][]{
    \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}
    {\textstyle \sum_{#2}      \displaystyle}
    {\textstyle \sum_{#2}^{#1} \displaystyle}
}
```

Note that it requires `\usepackage{xifthen}`.

I then, for example, call `\sumt[n-1]{i=1} k_i` to get the same as I would've got from `\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} k_i`. Note that this does enforce that everything after is in display-mode, which may or may not be unhelpful. Once an do a similar thing with `\int` and `\prod`. Note that this is written backwards compared with the usual.

Ideally I'd have both arguments optional, and in the order `\sum[lower][upper]`. (I'm not sure what effect the blank `^{}` has.) Someone with greater tex prowess than me would need to be called up for that, though!

---

For example, the minimalistic code

```
\begin{align*}
    a &+ \sumt[n-1]{i=1} i = 3\\
    a &+ \textstyle\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i = 3
\end{align*}
```

produces the following image.

[image]

Comment: This will enforce `\textstyle` from `\sumt` on.

Comment: Ah yes, you are right. I missed a set of braces when typing it here (but not when I tested)

Comment: The braces make the entire `\sumt{#1}{#2}` an ordinary symbol, not an Op atom, which can have adverse effects on spacing. Try with `\sumt{i=1}{n-1}i` and `\textstyle\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i`.

Comment: Hmm, yes, I see. I had expected this behaviour, but then the example I tried didn't have this issue! The updated answer, I don't think, has this issue (but is starting to become a bit cumbersome)...?

Comment: The difference is that `\log` is an operator; TeX inserts a thin space between an Ord and an Op or two Op atoms, but not between two Ord atoms.

Comment: Ah, I see. I think the suggestion that the edit I've just made rectifies this issue. It does force `\displaystyle`, but that's what one would normally have in a display, so maybe not so bad...