# Write text (or symbol) vertically below another symbol in latex

Tags: vertical-alignment, math-operators

I have to write some equations in latex, my Latex equation:

```
    \begin{align}
G _{a_{1},\ldots ,a_{k}}\ast_{b_{1},\ldots ,b_{k}} G^{\prime }=G^{\prime \prime }
\end{align}
```

How can I make the text like this:
[image]

I have to write an equations in latex like this:
[image]

Comment: Where do you want the baseline?

Comment: You can use [this approach by **egreg**](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231408/how-do-i-modify-the-size-of-s-the-summation-operand/231414#231414) and only change `\mathcal{S}` to `\ast`.

Answer (score 2):

I use a `\Centerstack` to accomplish the stack.  I place the top and bottom items in a `\mathsf` wrapper, and I introduce `\coresym[scale]{symbol}{subscript/superscript}` to center the core `symbol` and scale it as needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\newcommand\coresym[3][1]{\phantom{#3}\scalebox{#1}{$#2$}#3}
\setstackgap{L}{.9\baselineskip}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\[
\Centerstack{\mathsf{G} \\ \coresym[1.3]{*}{^1_2} \\ \mathsf{G}} =  ax + b
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

I also shrunk the stacking gap between items to `.9\baselineskip`, but that can be changed to suit.  Here it is shrunk to `.7\baselineskip`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You will probably want to make a macro to simplify.  I wasn't sure what to make an argument and what to leave fixed.

[image: math sym]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathabx}% for \Asterisk

\begin{document}
$\displaystyle A = \vcenter{\baselineskip=0pt\hbox{$G$}\hbox{$\displaystyle *_{\scriptscriptstyle 2}^{\scriptscriptstyle 1}$}\hbox{$G$}}
= \vcenter{\baselineskip=0pt\hbox{$G$}\hbox{$\displaystyle \Asterisk_{\scriptscriptstyle 2}^{\scriptscriptstyle 1}$}\hbox{$G$}}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about your intentions. Here's an attempt:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\xasterisk}[4]{%
  {\mathop{*^{#1}_{#2}}\limits^{#3}_{#4}}%
}

\begin{document}
\[
\xasterisk{1}{2}{\mathsf{G}}{\mathsf{G}}=ax+b
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\asteriskG}[4]{{\mathop{\ast}\limits
      _{\textsf{\bfseries\scriptsize#1}}
      ^{\textsf{\bfseries\scriptsize#2}} \mkern-2mu
    {}_{\scriptscriptstyle#3}
      ^{\scriptscriptstyle#4}}
}
\begin{document}
$\asteriskG{G}{G}{2}{1}=ax+b$
\end{document}
```

If you need a five-pointed instead of six-pointed star, use `\star` instead of `\ast`. How important is it that the two letters `G` be typeset in bold sans-serif style?