# Alternative sum symbol for Neo Euler

Tags: math-mode, fonts, unicode

I love the (unicode) Neo Euler font from Hermann Zapf & Khaled Hosny. The only caveat is the `\sum` symbol, which is in my opinion just ugly:

[image]

I hear it also from other people, therefore I wonder if someone designed an alternative sum symbol for Neo Euler?

I am aware, that I could load this symbol from the other unicode math packages (Cambria, Asana, XITS, LM, Lucida, Latin Modern, TeX Gyre), but they don't look nice with Neo Euler.

[image]

Comment: Without knowing what you dislike about the NeoEuler symbol and what you'd like to have…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility is to use my technique at [How are big operators defined?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116506/how-are-big-operators-defined/116538#116538) to define `\varsum`, which takes the `\Sigma` glyph from the same font family and scales it to the size of `\sum`.

This approach has the advantage of using a glyph already in that font family.  However, you may find the weight too heavy is the downside.

Note that I don't have the neo Euler font, so I demonstrate below with the `eulervm` package.  After showing the `\Sigma` glyph on the first line, I then compare equations using `\sum` and `\varsum` in all math styles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eulervm,scalerel,mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\varsum}{\scalerel*{\Sigma}{\sum}}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\Sigma &= 0\\
(x+a)^n &= \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k} x^k a^{n-k}\\
(x+a)^n &= \varsum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k} x^k a^{n-k}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
(x+a)^n &= \textstyle\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k} x^k a^{n-k}\\
(x+a)^n &= \textstyle\varsum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k} x^k a^{n-k}
\end{align}

\[
\scriptstyle(x+a)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k} x^k a^{n-k}\\
\]
\[
\scriptstyle(x+a)^n = \varsum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k} x^k a^{n-k}\\
\]

\[
\scriptscriptstyle(x+a)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k} x^k a^{n-k}\\
\]
\[
\scriptscriptstyle(x+a)^n = \varsum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k} x^k a^{n-k}\\
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

And here is a version that takes the `\Sigma` glyph in `\scriptstyle` by defining `\varsum` as

```
\DeclareMathOperator*{\varsum}{\scalerel*{\scriptstyle\Sigma}{\sum}}
```

It produces a wider result

[image]

Comment: Thx. Sigma has a nice shape, although a bit bold. I will try to make it thinner in a font editor.

Comment: @ManuelSchmidt That would be an ideal solution.