# How to control the size of math symbols in an equation?

Tags: math-mode, equations

I've been struggling with this task for some time now. Basically I want to make this:

[image]

Into something like this:

[image]

I've tried `\mathlarger` from `relsize` package, but it simply didn't work (no effect at all). If it interests anyone, this is the equation code:

```
\begin{equation}
f_1(x) = min \bigg\{ \sum_{m=1}^{M} \sum_{i=I_{sm}}^{I{em}-N_m} \bigg(\sum_{n=i}^{i +(N_m-1)} P_m[n-i]T_sC[n]\bigg)u_{mi} \bigg\}
\end{equation}
```

Thank you!!

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How are big operators defined?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/116506/5764)

Comment: Why would you turn a nice output into a monster?

Comment: My plan is to keep the three summation symbols at the same size, but bigger than the one outputed by tex. I believe the equation would be better visualized like that. Can you explain further why you think it will become a monster? Is there any reason besides personal aesthetics preferences?

Comment: At least the non-italicised 'min' is an improvement...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use Steven B. Segletes’ `scalerel` package and do something like the following:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand*{\biggsum}{\mathop{\stretchrel*{\sum}{\bigg(}}\limits}



\begin{document}

Text before
\begin{equation}
    f_1(x) = \min \bigg\{ \biggsum_{m=1}^{M} \biggsum_{i=I_{sm}}^{I{em}-N_m}
        \bigg(\sum_{n=i}^{i +(N_m-1)} P_m[n-i]T_sC[n]\bigg)u_{mi} \bigg\}
\end{equation}
Text after.

\end{document}
```

I’m not accepting any responsibility for the (very poor) typographical quality of the output! (:-)  Indeed, what you get is

[image: Output of the above code]

that is, something I would never ever use in a paper of mine; but it is, nonetheless, close to what you asked for.

---

## Addition

The OP has made clear that (s)he had not the (pretty devious ;-) intent of stretching out the summation symbol, as the posted image suggested, but rather to scale it up.  As explained in the comments, this is achieved by simply replacing the `\stretchrel` command with `\scalerel`:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand*{\biggsum}{\mathop{\scalerel*{\sum}{\bigg(}}\limits}



\begin{document}

Text before.  Note that, this time, I'm using 
\verb|\left\{|\,\ldots\verb|\right\}|.
\begin{equation}
    f_1(x) = \min \left\{ \biggsum_{m=1}^{M} \biggsum_{i=I_{sm}}^{I{em}-N_m}
        \bigg(\sum_{n=i}^{i +(N_m-1)} P_m[n-i]T_sC[n]\bigg)u_{mi} \right\}
\end{equation}
Text after.

Another possibility is to use \verb|\Biggl\{|\,\ldots\verb|\Biggr\}| (which 
looks better, IMHO\@).
\begin{equation}
    f_1(x) = \min \Biggl\{ \biggsum_{m=1}^{M} \biggsum_{i=I_{sm}}^{I{em}-N_m}
        \bigg(\sum_{n=i}^{i +(N_m-1)} P_m[n-i]T_sC[n]\bigg)u_{mi} \Biggr\}
\end{equation}
Text after.

\end{document}
```

And here’s the new output:

[image: Output of the second code sample]

---

## Second Addition

Actually, there is another, and, I believe, much simpler possibility, that requires nothing more than the `amsfonts` package (which is automatically loaded when you use the `amsmath` package).  The following code illustrates it:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{amsfonts}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*\@MyHelperSum[1]{%
    \mathop{\hbox{#1$\m@th\displaystyle\sum$}}\limits
}
% Here is a whole series of larger and larger summation symbols:
\newcommand*\largesum{\@MyHelperSum\large}
\newcommand*\Largesum{\@MyHelperSum\Large}
\newcommand*\LARGEsum{\@MyHelperSum\LARGE}
\newcommand*\hugesum {\@MyHelperSum\huge }
\newcommand*\Hugesum {\@MyHelperSum\Huge }

\makeatother



\begin{document}

Text before.  Note that, this time, I'm using 
\verb|\left\{|\,\ldots\verb|\right\}|.
\begin{equation}
    f_1(x) = \min \left\{ \Largesum_{m=1}^{M} \Largesum_{i=I_{sm}}^{I{em}-N_m}
        \bigg(\sum_{n=i}^{i +(N_m-1)} P_m[n-i]T_sC[n]\bigg)u_{mi} \right\}
\end{equation}
Text after.

Another possibility is to use \verb|\Biggl\{|\,\ldots\verb|\Biggr\}| (which 
looks better, IMHO\@).
\begin{equation}
    f_1(x) = \min \Biggl\{ \Largesum_{m=1}^{M} \Largesum_{i=I_{sm}}^{I{em}-N_m}
        \bigg(\sum_{n=i}^{i +(N_m-1)} P_m[n-i]T_sC[n]\bigg)u_{mi} \Biggr\}
\end{equation}
Text after.

\end{document}
```

The output is

[image: Output of the third code sample]

You might want to try other sizes, too, *e.g.*, `\LARGEsum`.

Note the following:

1. The `amsfonts` package is required because, without it,
   the `cmex10` font would be loaded at fixed size; indeed,
   the `omxcmex.fd` file contains the lines

   ```
   \DeclareFontFamily{OMX}{cmex}{}
   \DeclareFontShape{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}{%
      <->sfixed*cmex10%
      }{}
   ```

   whereas `amsfonts.sty` has

   ```
   \DeclareFontShape{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}{%
          <-7.5>cmex7%
       <7.5-8.5>cmex8%
       <8.5-9.5>cmex9%
       <9.5->cmex10%
   }{}%
   ```

   (what makes the difference, here, is the line that says
   `<9.5->cmex10`, the other three are relevant for smaller sizes).
2. This approach makes direct use of fonts that should be available
   on all sites at the required size, without needing any special help
   from the rendering device (or typesetting engine) to magnify the
   glyphs; it should work correctly even with bitmapped fonts, like
   those that were used decades ago (provided, of course, that the
   standard sizes are properly installed, as already said).
   So, it ensures maximum portability.
3. On the other hand, if outline fonts are being used
   (as it is ordinarily the case
   since at least fifteen years ago), this solution will end up
   asking the rendering device to scale up the summation symbol
   contained in the `cmex10` font, exactly as it happens when the
   `scalerel` package is used.
4. This solution works only if you want to magnify the symbol without
   distorting it: that’s why I didn’t think of it in the first place.
5. Drawback: this solution is of course inadequate if you are already
   typesetting in, say, `\Huge` size. (;-)

---

## Third Addition

Just to wrap this discussion up, I’d finally like to remark that the OP’s original idea of using the `relsize` package and its `\mathlarger` command—which is a perfectly viable solution too—didn’t succeed precisely for the same reason hinted at above: in order for it to work, one should also load the `amsfonts` package.  Indeed, the documentation of the `relsize` package explicitly warn users about this fact (actually, it mentions the `exscale` package, which provides similar functionality).

Comment: Perhaps consider changing your `\biggsum` to `\mathop{\biggsum}\limits`.  That is, `\newcommand*{\biggsum}{\mathop{\stretchrel*{\sum}{\bigg(}}\limits}`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: Of course, you are quite right!  In the hurry, I overlooked this essential detail.  Thank you.

Comment: I would then also resort to `\left\{` syntax in lieu of the leading `\bigg\{`

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your reply it for sure made the sum symbol taller. Is there a way I can change the size of it, keeping its proportions? Also when modifying the sum symbol the parenthesis and brackets will have to become larger too, I suppose I can use a similar solution for them? Could you elaborate more in your last comment in the reply, that you'd never do such a thing in a paper of yours? Thanks again!

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: I agree that `\left\{` is preferable, but I am waiting for the OP to clarify her/his requirements.

Comment: You might also consider aspect-ratio limiting the stretch, with something like `\newcommand*{\biggsum}{\mathop{\stretchrel*[90]{\sum}{\bigg(}}\limits}`.

Comment: @user1050181: Just use `\scalerel` instead of `\stretchrel`.  For what concerns the final remark, i have nothing to elaborate on: simply, I would never ever use such a stretched symbol.

Comment: @user1050181  There is also a `\scalerel` in addition to a `\stretchrel`.  The former preserves aspect ratio, though it provides a width limiter as an optional argument.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti it worked perfectly with the \scalerel command. I'll accept your answer but I believe it would be even better if you added the \scalerel to it! ;) Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 7):

The [mtpro2](http://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html) package offers the `\xl`, `\XL`, and `\XXL` modifiers that can be prefixed to "large" math operators such as `\sum`, `\prod`, and `\int` to create increasingly larger symbols. (Well, there's also the `\XXXL` modifier, which produces operator symbols that are 5 centimeters [!] tall, but let's not go there.)

Note that the full `mtpro2` package isn't free of charge. However, its "lite" subset, which is all that's needed for this case, is free.

The following screenshot shows the normal displaymath-style size for `\sum` as well as `\xl\sum`, `\XL\sum`, and `\XXL\sum` for the two outer `\sum` symbols. The innermost `\sum` is not modified on purpose. I'm pretty sure that rows 3 and 4 will qualify as being "monstrous" in @egreg's classification system.

[image]

```
\usepackage{newtxtext,amsmath}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
f_1(x) &= \min \biggl\{\, \sum_{m=1}^{M} \sum_{i=I_{sm}}^{I_{em}-N_m} 
          \biggl(\,\sum_{n=i}^{i +N_m-1} P_m[n-i]T_sC[n]\biggr)u_{mi} \biggr\}\\
f_1(x) &= \min \Biggl\{ \xl\sum_{m=1}^{M} \xl\sum_{i=I_{sm}}^{I_{em}-N_m} 
          \biggl(\,\sum_{n=i}^{i +N_m-1} P_m[n-i]T_sC[n]\biggr)u_{mi} \Biggr\}\\
f_1(x) &= \min \LEFTRIGHT\{\}{ \XL\sum_{m=1}^{M} \XL\sum_{i=I_{sm}}^{I_{em}-N_m} 
          \biggl(\,\sum_{n=i}^{i +N_m-1} P_m[n-i]T_sC[n]\biggr)u_{mi}}\\
f_1(x) &= \min \LEFTRIGHT\{\}{ \XXL\sum_{m=1}^{M} \XXL\sum_{i=I_{sm}}^{I_{em}-N_m} 
          \biggl(\,\sum_{n=i}^{i +N_m-1} P_m[n-i]T_sC[n]\biggr)u_{mi}}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your answer seems to solve all my problems. But to install a package in MikTek using windows is very troublesome (if the package is not listed in the package manager). So it will take some time for me to test this. I'll comment again when I do. Thanks!