# Make big plus and big times symbols

Tags: symbols, unicode-math

I want to create from suitable symbols ‐ and *not* using TikZ or other drawing method — large sum (`\bigsum`) and large times (`\mybigtimes`) math symbols, for cartesian sum and cartesian product, respectively, that:

- are the same vertical size as `\bigcup` and `\bigcap`;
- have strokes with the same thickness as the curves in `\bigcup` and `\bigcap`;
- in the case of `\mybigtimes`, is scaled down horizontally only;
- will scale properly for in-line math, display math, etc. (presumably, by using `\mathchoice`; and
- will work with both pdfLaTeX and `XeLaTeX.

How can this be done?

Here is what I have so far. The output shown is produced only when the part after `This does \emph{not} work` is commented out.

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{iftex}

\ifTUTeX
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures=TeX }
  \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}[Scale=1.0]
  \setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
  \mathchardef\timessymbol=\numexpr\times-"2000\relax % WHAT IS THE NAME-NUMBER?
\else
  \RequirePackage[scaled=0.93]{newtxtext}
  \RequirePackage{newtxmath}%
  \mathchardef\timessymbol=\numexpr\times-"2000\relax % WHAT IS THE NAME-NUMBER?
\fi

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\bigplus}{\scalerel*{+}{\sum}}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\Bigplus}{\scalerel*{+}{\textstyle\sum}}

% Attempt to shrink a big times horizontally:
\DeclareMathOperator*{\mybigtimes}{\scalebox{0.7}[1]{\timessymbol}}

\begin{document}
\ifTUTeX With Xe\LaTeX\else With pdf\LaTeX\fi

\bigskip
These work, but geometry is wrong:

\bigskip

$\bigtimes_{n=0}^{\infty} X_{i} = \bigcup_{k=0}^{\infty}U_{k}$ 
\quad to shrink \verb!\bigtimes! horizontally (but not vertically)

\bigskip
$\bigplus_{n=0}^{\infty} X_{i} = \bigcap_{k=0}^{\infty}U_{k}$ \quad \verb!\bigsum! too thick 
%
\begin{gather*}
\bigtimes_{n=0}^{\infty} X_{i}= \bigcup_{k=0}^{\infty}U_{k}
\quad \text{to shrink bigtimes symbol horizontally (but not vertically)}
\\
\bigplus_{n=0}^{\infty} X_{i} = \bigcap_{k=0}^{\infty}U_{k} 
\quad \text{bigplus symbol too thick}
\end{gather*}

This does \emph{not} work:

$\mybigtimes_{n=0}^{\infty} X_{i}$
\[
\mybigtimes_{n=0}^{\infty} X_{i}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: XeLaTeX output]

[image: pdfLaTeX output]

**Related:**

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/394912/13492

[Big cartesian product & cartesian sum symbols with Lucida Math fonts?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/343591/big-cartesian-product-cartesian-sum-symbols-with-lucida-math-fonts)

**Continuation:** See [Make non-square bigtimes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/552679/make-non-square-bigtimes).

Comment: The requirement that the strokes have the same thickness means that you probably won’t be able to get what you want by scaling an existing symbol.  You could instead draw a pair of intersecting lines, using TikZ, on a canvas set to the height and depth of `\cup`, and select the thickness based on `\mathchoice`.

Comment: A completely satisfactory solution is given by https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/552914/13492.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `\pdfliteral` directly in pdfTeX:

```
\def\mybigtimes{\mathop{\mathchoice{%display:
   \vcenter{\hbox to10bp{\vrule height15bp width0pt \pdfliteral{
   q 1 J .8 w 0 1 m 10 14 l S 0 14 m 10 1 l S Q
}\hss}}}{%text:
   \vcenter{\hbox to10bp{\kern1bp\vrule height10bp width0pt \pdfliteral{
   q 1 J .65 w 0 0 m 8 10 l S 0 10 m 8 0 l S Q
}\hss}}}{\times}{\times}%script, scriptscript not defined
}}

\def\mybigplus{\mathop{\mathchoice{%display:
   \vcenter{\hbox to12bp{\vrule height15bp width0pt \pdfliteral{
   q 1 J .8 w 0 7.5 m 12 7.5 l S 6 1 m 6 14 l S Q
}\hss}}}{%text:
   \vcenter{\hbox to12bp{\kern1bp\vrule height10bp width0pt \pdfliteral{
   q 1 J .65 w 0 5 m 10 5 l S 5 0 m 5 10 l S Q
}\hss}}}{+}{+}%script, scriptscript not defined
}}
```

You can define `\def\pdfliteral#1{\special{pdf:literal #1}}` in XeTeX and then you can use the same macros.

[image: myplus]

Comment: I want the symbols to be glyphs with unicode codes, so that the pdf output will pass PDF A/2-u validation. Isn't this method essentially just drawing, hence not producing such a unicode-known glyph?

Comment: If I am going to get what is essentially a drawing with this method, is there any particular advantage to it over using, say, TikZ?

Comment: @murray I cannot find Unicode slot for bigsum and bigtimes. So, these symbols cannot be realized as given Unicode-known glyphs.

Comment: `\pdfliteral` is better (in such simple tasks) than TikZ because it is much more simpler, compact and you need not to load any external package (tikz has more than 30k lines of code).

Comment: I will also need a `script` style of these. And I will need a rectangular box command `\bigbox` producing a rectangular box operator having the same dimensions as the `\bigtimes`; how would one do that?

Answer (score 4):

This is the image with `pdflatex`:

[image]

This is the image with `xelatex`:

[image]
For mysterious reasons, the developers of TeX Gyre Termes Math decided not to give all big operators the same dimensions. It's up to you to decide whether to use `\bigcup` as a model or `\sum` as in the code below.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,pict2e}
\usepackage{iftex}

\ifTUTeX
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}[Scale=1.0]
  \setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\else
  \usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\fi

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\murray@big}[1]{%
  \mathop{\vphantom{\sum}\mathpalette\murray@makebig{#1}}\slimits@
}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \DeclareRobustCommand{\bigplus}{\DOTSB\murray@big\murray@plus}%
  \DeclareRobustCommand{\bigtimes}{\DOTSB\murray@big\murray@times}%
}

\newcommand{\murray@makebig}[2]{%
  \vcenter{%
    \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\sum$}%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{0.9\dimexpr\ht\z@+\dp\z@}%
    \hbox{\kern0.1\wd\z@\murray@draw{#1}{#2}\kern0.1\wd\z@}%
  }%
}

\newcommand{\murray@draw}[2]{%
  \begin{picture}(1,1)
    \linethickness{%
      \ifx#1\displaystyle 1.2\fontdimen8\textfont3\else
      \ifx#1\textstyle 1.1\fontdimen8\textfont3\else
      \ifx#1\scriptstyle1\fontdimen8\scriptfont3\else
      1\fontdimen8\scriptscriptfont3\fi\fi\fi
    }%
    #2
  \end{picture}%
}


\newcommand{\murray@plus}{%
  \roundcap
  \Line(0.5,0)(0.5,1)
  \Line(0,0.5)(1,0.5)
}
\newcommand{\murray@times}{%
  \roundcap
  \Line(0.14645,0.14645)(0.85355,0.85355)
  \Line(0.14646,0.85355)(0.85355,0.14645)
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\displaystyle\bigplus_{k=0}^\infty \bigcup_{k=0}^\infty \bigtimes_{k=0}^\infty$

\medskip

$\textstyle\bigplus_{k=0}^\infty \bigcup_{k=0}^\infty \bigtimes_{k=0}^\infty$

\medskip

$\scriptstyle\bigplus_{k=0}^\infty \bigcup_{k=0}^\infty \bigtimes_{k=0}^\infty$

\medskip

$\scriptscriptstyle\bigplus_{k=0}^\infty \bigcup_{k=0}^\infty \bigtimes_{k=0}^\infty$

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid drawing the symbols, whether with TikZ or the picture environment, etc. The purpose is to get a glyph that will be unicode, so that the pdf output will pass PDF A/2-u validation.

Comment: The `\bigtimes` here does *not* shrink horizontally what is essentially a rotated cross, so that the symbol width is smaller than its height, i.e., the two lines no longer cross at 90-degree angles.

Comment: If I am going to get what is essentially a drawing with this method, is there any particular advantage to it over using, say, TikZ?

Comment: @murray It's simpler than TikZ. If you want to shrink the times symbol, do it.

Comment: Please see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/552679/make-non-square-bigtimes for more about this.

Comment: @murray I modified the code so that `\bigtimes` is now a rotated `\bigplus`, but occupies the same space.