# Make non-square bigtimes

Tags: math-mode, symbols, math-operators

In https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/552557/13492, a method is shown to create both a `\bigtimes` symbol (for Cartesian products of families) and a `\bigplus` symbol (for Cartesian sums of families).

**Questions:**

1. How can that be modified so that the `\bigtimes` does *not* have a square shape, that is, so that the two strokes do *not* cross at right angles, thereby making the symbol narrower than its height.
2. The answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/552769/13492 includes a `\scalebox` with a horizontal `\scalefactor` whose value is essentially hard-coded according to which symbol is being targeted. Can the code with `\scalefactor` be modified to incorporate an additional argument, defaulting to 1, for that horizontal scale factor?
3. Given the intended usage, where both symbols take sub- and/or super-scripts for indexing, does one not need either `\DeclareMathOperator` or `\mathop`? If so, how should that be incorporated; if not, why not?

**Source:** The code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/552557/13492 is supplemented by two different — commented-out — methods I tried to use to accomplish the goal of 1.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,pict2e}
\usepackage{iftex}

\ifTUTeX
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}[Scale=1.0]
  \setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\else
  \usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\fi

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\my@big}[1]{%
  \mathop{\vphantom{\sum}\mathpalette\my@makebig{#1}}\slimits@
}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \DeclareRobustCommand{\bigplus}{\DOTSB\my@big\my@plus}%
  \DeclareRobustCommand{\bigtimes}{\DOTSB\my@big\my@times}%
}
\newcommand{\my@makebig}[2]{%
  \vcenter{%
    \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\sum$}%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{0.9\dimexpr\ht\z@+\dp\z@}%
    \hbox{\kern0.1\wd\z@\my@draw{#1}{#2}\kern0.1\wd\z@}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\my@draw}[2]{%
  \begin{picture}(1,1)
    \linethickness{%
      \ifx#1\displaystyle 1.2\fontdimen8\textfont3\else
      \ifx#1\textstyle 1.1\fontdimen8\textfont3\else
      \ifx#1\scriptstyle1\fontdimen8\scriptfont3\else
      1\fontdimen8\scriptscriptfont3\fi\fi\fi
    }%
    #2
  \end{picture}%
}
\newcommand{\my@plus}{%
  \roundcap
  \Line(0.5,0)(0.5,1)
  \Line(0,0.5)(1,0.5)
}
\newcommand{\my@times}{%
  \roundcap
  \Line(0,0)(1,1)
  \Line(0,1)(1,0)
}

%% Attempt #1 to try to reshape \bigtimes...
%% ...leaves too much space after \bigtimes...
%% ... and displaystyle puts sub- & super-scripts off-center
%\newcommand{\my@times}{%
%  \roundcap
%  \Line(0,0)(0.75,1)
%  \Line(0,1)(0.75,0)
%}

%% Attempt #2 to reshape \bigtimes, using \scalebox instead ...
%% ... makes lines too thin and leaves too much space after \bigtmies...
%% ... and displaystyle puts sub- & super-scripts off-center:
%\newcommand{\my@@times}{%
%  \roundcap
%  \Line(0,0)(1,1)
%  \Line(0,1)(1,0)
%}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\newcommand{\my@times}{%
%  \scalebox{0.85}[1]{\my@@times}%
%}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

In-line $
\bigplus_{i\in I} X_i  = \bigtimes_{j\in J} Y_i = \bigcup_{i\in I} Z_{i} =  \bigcap_{n\in I} Z_{i} 
$ here.
\[
\bigplus_{i\in I} X_i = \bigtimes_{j\in J} Y_i = \bigcup_{i\in I} Z_i =  \bigcap_{n\in I} Z_{i} 
\]

In-line $
\bigplus_{i=0}^{\infty} X_i  = \bigtimes_{j=0}^{\infty} Y_i = \bigcup_{i=0}^{\infty} Z_{i} =  \bigcap_{n=0}^{\infty} Z_{i} 
$ here.
\[
\bigplus_{i=0}^{\infty} X_i = \bigtimes_{j=0}^{\infty} Y_i = \bigcup_{i=0}^{\infty} Z_i =  \bigcap_{n=0}^{\infty} Z_{i} 
\]
\end{document}
```

**Output:** All output shown was produced using XeLaTeX; the results are similar if pdfLaTeX is used instead.

First is the output using the original code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/552557/13492.

[image: Original, square-shape bigtimes]

Second, the output if my `Attempt 1` is used, which leaves too much space after `\bigtimes`in inline mode and puts sub- & super-scripts off-center in display mode:

[image: Attempt #1 bigtimes]

Third, the output if my `Attempt 2` is used, which also leaves too much space after `\bigtimes`in inline mode and puts sub- & super-scripts off-center in display mode:

[image: Attempt #2 bigtimes using scalebox]

Comment: A completely satisfactory solution is given by https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/552914/13492.

Answer (score 1):

By creating separate `\my@narrowbig`, `\my@narrowmakebig`, and `\my@narrowdraw`, and `\my@narrowtimes` commands, using a drawing canvas 0.75 wide and 1 high, I can get a more-or-less suitable non-square `\bigtimes` operator symbol for Cartesian product. And similarly a `\bigbox` operator symbol for box product (in the topological sense).

The results:

[image: non-square, corrected, bigtimes and bigbox]

The code is shown below.

**Complaints:**

1. When viewed on-screen, the strokes of the new symbols seem OK; but when printed, the strokes of `\bigtimes`, `\bigsum`, and `\bigbox` seem a bit too thick as compared to that of `\bigcup` an `\bigcap`. *How should that be fixed?*
2. It seems like a terrible waste of code to have to create two sets of commands — one for `\bigsum` and another for the other new operator symbols. *Is there some way to combine the codes?*

**The modified source:**

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,pict2e}
\usepackage{iftex}

\ifTUTeX
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}[Scale=1.0]
  \setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\else
  \usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\fi

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\my@big}[1]{%
  \mathop{\vphantom{\sum}\mathpalette\my@makebig{#1}}\slimits@
}
\newcommand{\my@narrowbig}[1]{%
  \mathop{\vphantom{\sum}\mathpalette\my@narrowmakebig{#1}}\slimits@
}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \DeclareRobustCommand{\bigplus}{\DOTSB\my@big\my@plus}%
  %\DeclareRobustCommand{\bigtimes}{\DOTSB\my@big\my@times}%
  \DeclareRobustCommand{\bigtimes}{\DOTSB\my@narrowbig\my@narrowtimes}%
  \DeclareRobustCommand{\bigbox}{\DOTSB\my@narrowbig\my@narrowbox}%
}
\newcommand{\my@makebig}[2]{%
  \vcenter{%
    \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\sum$}%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{0.9\dimexpr\ht\z@+\dp\z@}%
    \hbox{\kern0.1\wd\z@\my@draw{#1}{#2}\kern0.1\wd\z@}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\my@draw}[2]{%
  \begin{picture}(1,1)
    \linethickness{%
      \ifx#1\displaystyle 1.2\fontdimen8\textfont3\else
      \ifx#1\textstyle 1.1\fontdimen8\textfont3\else
      \ifx#1\scriptstyle1\fontdimen8\scriptfont3\else
      1\fontdimen8\scriptscriptfont3\fi\fi\fi
    }%
    #2
  \end{picture}%
}
\newcommand{\my@plus}{%
  \roundcap
  \Line(0.5,0)(0.5,1)
  \Line(0,0.5)(1,0.5)
}
\newcommand{\my@times}{%
  \roundcap
  \Line(0,0)(1,1)
  \Line(0,1)(1,0)
}
\newcommand{\my@narrowtimes}{%
  \roundcap
  \Line(0,0)(0.75,1)
  \Line(0,1)(0.75,0)
}
\newcommand{\my@narrowbox}{%
  %\roundcap
  \Line(0,0)(0.75,0)
  \Line(0.75,0)(0.75,1)
  \Line(0.75,1)(0,1)
  \Line(0,1)(0,0)
}
\newcommand{\my@narrowmakebig}[2]{%
  \vcenter{%
    \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\sum$}%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{0.9\dimexpr\ht\z@+\dp\z@}%
    \hbox{\kern0.1\wd\z@\my@narrowdraw{#1}{#2}\kern0.1\wd\z@}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\my@narrowdraw}[2]{%
  \begin{picture}(0.75,1)
    \linethickness{%
      \ifx#1\displaystyle 1.2\fontdimen8\textfont3\else
      \ifx#1\textstyle 1.1\fontdimen8\textfont3\else
      \ifx#1\scriptstyle1\fontdimen8\scriptfont3\else
      1\fontdimen8\scriptscriptfont3\fi\fi\fi
    }%
    #2
  \end{picture}%
}

%% Attempt #1 to try to reshape \bigtimes...
%% ...leaves too much space after \bigtimes
%\newcommand{\my@times}{%
%  \roundcap
%  \Line(0,0)(0.75,1)
%  \Line(0,1)(0.75,0)
%}

%% Attempt #2 to reshape \bigtimes, using \scalebox instead ...
%% ... makes lines too thin and leaves too much space after \bigtmies
%\newcommand{\my@@times}{%
%  \roundcap
%  \Line(0,0)(1,1)
%  \Line(0,1)(1,0)
%}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\newcommand{\my@times}{%
%  \scalebox{0.85}[1]{\my@@times}%
%}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

In-line $
\bigplus_{i\in I} X_i  = \bigtimes_{i\in J} Y_i = \bigbox_{i\in I} X_{i} = \bigcup_{i\in I} Z_{i} =  \bigcap_{n\in I} Z_{i} 
$ here.
\[
\bigplus_{i\in I} X_i = \bigtimes_{i\in J} Y_i = \bigbox_{i\in I} X_{i}= \bigcup_{i\in I} Z_i =  \bigcap_{n\in I} Z_{i} 
\]

In-line $
\bigplus_{i=0}^{\infty} X_i  = \bigtimes_{i=0}^{\infty} Y_i = \bigbox_{i=0}^{\infty} X_{i} = \bigcup_{i=0}^{\infty} Z_{i} =  \bigcap_{n=0}^{\infty} Z_{i} 
$ here.
\[
\bigplus_{i=0}^{\infty} X_i = \bigtimes_{i=0}^{\infty} Y_i = \bigbox_{i=0}^{\infty} X_{i} = \bigcup_{i=0}^{\infty} Z_i =  \bigcap_{n=0}^{\infty} Z_{i} 
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is only that in `\my@draw`, you use a `picture` environment which has a fixed width of `\unitlength`, regardless of the content of the `picture` environment. Hence, the `picture` environment for the `\bigtimes` symbol, which I guess you expected to have a width of `0.85\unitlength` because of the `\scalebox` in `\my@times`, still has a width of `\unitlength`.

There are probably many ways to fix that, but I think the easiest way would be to place the call of `\my@draw` in `\my@makebig` in the `\scalebox`, instead of placing the content of `\my@times` in the `\scalebox`. This is what I did in the following example.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,pict2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\newif\iftimes
\timesfalse
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\my@big}[1]{%
  \mathop{\vphantom{\sum}\mathpalette\my@makebig{#1}}\slimits@%
}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \DeclareRobustCommand{\bigplus}{\timesfalse\DOTSB\my@big\my@plus}%
  \DeclareRobustCommand{\bigtimes}{\timestrue\DOTSB\my@big\my@times}%
}
\newcommand{\my@makebig}[2]{%
  \iftimes
    \def\scalefactor{0.85}%
  \else
    \def\scalefactor{1}%
  \fi%
  \vcenter{%
    \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\sum$}%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{0.9\dimexpr\ht\z@+\dp\z@}%
    \hbox{\kern0.1\wd\z@\scalebox{\scalefactor}[1]{\my@draw{#1}{#2}}\kern0.1\wd\z@}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\my@draw}[2]{%
  \begin{picture}(1,1)
    \linethickness{%
      \ifx#1\displaystyle 1.2\fontdimen8\textfont3\else
      \ifx#1\textstyle 1.1\fontdimen8\textfont3\else
      \ifx#1\scriptstyle1\fontdimen8\scriptfont3\else
      1\fontdimen8\scriptscriptfont3\fi\fi\fi
    }%
    #2
  \end{picture}%
}
\newcommand{\my@plus}{%
  \roundcap
  \Line(0.5,0)(0.5,1)
  \Line(0,0.5)(1,0.5)
}
\newcommand{\my@times}{%
  \roundcap
  \Line(0,0)(1,1)
  \Line(0,1)(1,0)
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
In-line $
\bigplus_{i\in I} X_i  = \bigtimes_{j\in J} Y_i = \bigcup_{i\in I} Z_{i} =  \bigcap_{n\in I} Z_{i} 
$ here.
\[
\bigplus_{i\in I} X_i = \bigtimes_{j\in J} Y_i = \bigcup_{i\in I} Z_i =  \bigcap_{n\in I} Z_{i} 
\]

In-line $
\bigplus_{i=0}^{\infty} X_i  = \bigtimes_{j=0}^{\infty} Y_i = \bigcup_{i=0}^{\infty} Z_{i} =  \bigcap_{n=0}^{\infty} Z_{i} 
$ here.
\[
\bigplus_{i=0}^{\infty} X_i = \bigtimes_{j=0}^{\infty} Y_i = \bigcup_{i=0}^{\infty} Z_i =  \bigcap_{n=0}^{\infty} Z_{i} 
\]
\end{document}
```

I thought it was better to keep the same `\my@makebig` command for both `\bigtimes` and `\bigplus`, but I didn't want to mess with the call of `\mathpalette` in `\my@big` by adding another argument to `\my@makebig`. This is why I added the `\iftimes` statement, but I'm really no expert, and I guess there might be a better way to do that.

Anyway, here's the output of the example, which I compiled with pdfLaTeX.
[image]

Comment: I don't like that this hard-codes the scale factor. I very much want to be able to supply the scale factor as an additional argument, but taking a default value of 1.

Comment: A completely satisfactory solution is given by https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/552914/13492.