# How add new argument to command to control scaling?

Tags: macros, symbols, programming

The following code, slightly modified from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/552769/13492, allows creating new symbols `\bigplus`, `\bigtimes`, and `\bigbox`.

However, it hard-codes the scaling factor `\scalefactor` used to determine the horizontal shinkage of the symbols as produced, in the first instance, by applying in order `\my@makebig` and then `\my@big` to the pictures created by applying `\my@draw` to the basic forms `\my@plus`, `\my@times`, and `\my@box`.

The hard-coded `\scalefactor` is controlled by `\ifnarrow`.

**Question:**

How can the code be modified so as to *use a new, additional, argument to specify the scaling factor* directly and separately for each individual symbol (and such other similar symbols as I may choose to create).

Ideally, that new argument would be optional, defaulting to `1`.

I just don't see which of the commands to modify how so as to accomplish this.

**Clarification:**

The commands `\myplus`, `\mytimes`, and `\mybox` are to be left with each having *no* arguments. Rather, a new argument — should be added to `\my@big`, `\mymakebig`, and/or `\my@draw` (whichever are needed for the purpose). The new, optional, argument is then used *once*, in the preamble, separately for each of the `\big...` commands. In other words, to allow something like this in the preamble:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\bigtimes}{\DOTSB\my@big[0.8]\my@times}    
\DeclareRobustCommand{\bigplus}{\DOTSB\my@big\my@plus}
```

And then in the body of the document I still use, e.g.:

```
$\bigplus_{i\in I} X_i  = \bigtimes_{i\in J} Y_i$
```

**The code now:**

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,pict2e,graphicx}
\usepackage{iftex}

\ifTUTeX
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}[Scale=1.0]
  \setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\else
  \usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\fi

\newif\ifnarrow
\narrowfalse
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\my@big}[1]{%
  \mathop{\vphantom{\sum}\mathpalette\my@makebig{#1}}\slimits@%
}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \DeclareRobustCommand{\bigplus}{\narrowfalse\DOTSB\my@big\my@plus}%
  \DeclareRobustCommand{\bigtimes}{\narrowtrue\DOTSB\my@big\my@times}%
  \DeclareRobustCommand{\bigbox}{\narrowfalse\DOTSB\my@big\my@box}%
}
\newcommand{\my@makebig}[2]{%
  \ifnarrow
    \def\scalefactor{0.8}%
  \else
    \def\scalefactor{1}%
  \fi%
  \vcenter{%
    \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\sum$}%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{0.9\dimexpr\ht\z@+\dp\z@}%
    \hbox{\kern0.1\wd\z@\scalebox{\scalefactor}[1]{\my@draw{#1}{#2}}\kern0.1\wd\z@}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\my@draw}[2]{%
  \begin{picture}(1,1)
    \linethickness{%
      \ifx#1\displaystyle 1.15\fontdimen8\textfont3\else
      \ifx#1\textstyle 1.05\fontdimen8\textfont3\else
      \ifx#1\scriptstyle1\fontdimen8\scriptfont3\else
      1\fontdimen8\scriptscriptfont3\fi\fi\fi
    }%
    #2
  \end{picture}%
}

\newcommand{\my@plus}{%
  \roundcap
  \Line(0.5,0)(0.5,1)
  \Line(0,0.5)(1,0.5)
}
\newcommand{\my@times}{%
  \roundcap
  \Line(0,0)(1,1)
  \Line(0,1)(1,0)
}
\newcommand{\my@box}{%
  \roundcap
  \Line(0,0)(1,0)
  \Line(1,0)(1,1)
  \Line(1,1)(0,1)
  \Line(0,1)(0,0)
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

In-line $
\bigplus_{i\in I} X_i  = \bigtimes_{i\in J} Y_i = \bigbox_{i\in I} X_{i} = \bigcap_{i\in I} Z_{i} 
=  \bigcup_{n\in I} Z_{i}  = \sum_{i \in I} H_{i}
$. Display:
\[
\bigplus_{i\in I} X_i = \bigtimes_{i\in J} Y_i = \bigbox_{i\in I} X_{i}= \bigcap_{i\in I} Z_i 
=  \bigcup_{n\in I} Z_{i} = \sum_{i \in I} H_{i}
\]

In-line $
\bigplus_{i=0}^{\infty} X_i  = \bigtimes_{i=0}^{\infty} Y_i = \bigbox_{i=0}^{\infty} X_{i} 
= \bigcap_{i=0}^{\infty} Z_{i} =  \bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty} Z_{i} = \sum_{i =0}^{\infty} H_{i}
$. Display:
\[
\bigplus_{i=0}^{\infty} X_i = \bigtimes_{i=0}^{\infty} Y_i = \bigbox_{i=0}^{\infty} X_{i} 
= \bigcap_{i=0}^{\infty} Z_i =  \bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty} Z_{i} = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} H_{i}
\]
\end{document}
```

**Output:** This is what `xelatex` produces; the output from `pdflatex` is similar.

[image: big ops symbols]

**Related:**  The issue arises from my original question [Make big plus and big times symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/552535/make-big-plus-and-big-times-symbols/552557#552557) and the answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/552557/13492 to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

REVISED, based on comment.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,pict2e,graphicx}
\usepackage{iftex}

\ifTUTeX
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}[Scale=1.0]
  \setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\else
  \usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\fi

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\my@big}[2][1]{%
  \mathop{\vphantom{\sum}\def\scalefactor{#1}\mathpalette\my@makebig{#2}}\slimits@%
}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \DeclareRobustCommand{\bigplus}{\DOTSB\my@big[.5]\my@plus}%
  \DeclareRobustCommand{\bigtimes}{\DOTSB\my@big[.75]\my@times}%
  \DeclareRobustCommand{\bigbox}{\DOTSB\my@big\my@box}%
}
\newcommand{\my@makebig}[2]{%
  \vcenter{%
    \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\sum$}%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{0.9\dimexpr\ht\z@+\dp\z@}%
    \hbox{\kern0.1\wd\z@\scalebox{\scalefactor}[1]{\my@draw{#1}{#2}}\kern0.1\wd\z@}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\my@draw}[2]{%
  \begin{picture}(1,1)
    \linethickness{%
      \ifx#1\displaystyle 1.15\fontdimen8\textfont3\else
      \ifx#1\textstyle 1.05\fontdimen8\textfont3\else
      \ifx#1\scriptstyle1\fontdimen8\scriptfont3\else
      1\fontdimen8\scriptscriptfont3\fi\fi\fi
    }%
    #2
  \end{picture}%
}

\newcommand{\my@plus}{%
  \roundcap
  \Line(0.5,0)(0.5,1)
  \Line(0,0.5)(1,0.5)
}
\newcommand{\my@times}{%
  \roundcap
  \Line(0,0)(1,1)
  \Line(0,1)(1,0)
}
\newcommand{\my@box}{%
  \roundcap
  \Line(0,0)(1,0)
  \Line(1,0)(1,1)
  \Line(1,1)(0,1)
  \Line(0,1)(0,0)
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

In-line $
\bigplus_{i\in I} X_i  = \bigtimes_{i\in J} Y_i = \bigbox_{i\in I} X_{i} = \bigcap_{i\in I} Z_{i} 
=  \bigcup_{n\in I} Z_{i}  = \sum_{i \in I} H_{i}
$. Display:
\[
\bigplus_{i\in I} X_i = \bigtimes_{i\in J} Y_i = \bigbox_{i\in I} X_{i}= \bigcap_{i\in I} Z_i 
=  \bigcup_{n\in I} Z_{i} = \sum_{i \in I} H_{i}
\]

In-line $
\bigplus_{i=0}^{\infty} X_i  = \bigtimes_{i=0}^{\infty} Y_i = \bigbox_{i=0}^{\infty} X_{i} 
= \bigcap_{i=0}^{\infty} Z_{i} =  \bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty} Z_{i} = \sum_{i =0}^{\infty} H_{i}
$. Display:
\[
\bigplus_{i=0}^{\infty} X_i = \bigtimes_{i=0}^{\infty} Y_i = \bigbox_{i=0}^{\infty} X_{i} 
= \bigcap_{i=0}^{\infty} Z_i =  \bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty} Z_{i} = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} H_{i}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's not the way I want to use the new argument: I want to use the argument *once*, in each of the definitions of \bigplus`, `\bigtimes`, `\bigbox` and *not* in the body of the document. So those three commands should *not* themselves have any arguments whatsoever. Thus I want to be able to do in the preamble something like `\DeclareRobustCommand{\bigtimes}{\DOTSB\my@big[0.8]\my@times}` and `\DeclareRobustCommand{\bigplus}{\DOTSB\my@big\my@plus}`. Thus scaling factors are fixed (separately) in preamble for each `\big...` command, and the `\big...` commands are used *without* arguments.

Comment: @murray Done, per your request.

Comment: Preamble code *exactly* what I want, thank you! (But I would *not* be using the optional `[.5]` in the body of the document, since that produces spurious output [.5] after the symbols! after the big symbols in the first "In-line" and "Display" output!)

Comment: @murray Of course.  Silly me.  Fixed.