# How to create your own integral sign with limits

Tags: macros, math-operators, integral

Following on from this question, I'd like to be able to do this but with an integral sign.

The proposed solution is the following:

```
\newcommand{\opA}{\mathop{\vphantom{\sum}\mathchoice
   {\vcenter{\hbox{\huge A}}} 
   {\vcenter{\hbox{\Large A}}}{\mathrm{A}}{\mathrm{A}}}\displaylimits}
```

I tried to modify this for an integral sign:

```
\newcommand{\integral}[2]{\mathop{\vphantom{\int}\mathchoice
    {\huge\int #1 \, d#2}
    {\Large\int #1 \, d#2}{\mathrm{A}}{\mathrm{A}}}\displaylimits}
```

Applying this via `\integral{x}{x}_0^1` for instance then gives the following:

[image: Example Integral]

However, this centres the limits above and below the integral instead of where you want them at the left.

So my question is: how to align them in the right place? Also, what should I write instead of `\mathrm{A}` in the other two type modes that are shown above?

Thanks!

Comment: Possibly related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39181/big-integral-sign, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116506/how-are-big-operators-defined.  See, also, `\DeclareMathOperator` macro from the `amsmath` package.

Comment: Have you tried using makebox or hspace commands?

Comment: unrelated, but you also might want to put $d$ in a mathrm environment since it's an operator, not a variable

Comment: @JJM Driessen, no I haven't as I don't know much about it, would using those still allow you to use _0^1 to specify the limits?

Answer (score 2):

Easy but inflexible answer

```
\def\integral#1#2_#3^#4{\int_{#3}^{#4}\mathopen{}#1\mathclose{}\mathop{}\!d#4\mathclose{}}
```

And then you have to always use the command with the limits and in that order. So if you don't want limits you would need `\integral{f(x)}{x}_{}^{}`.

---

A better solution would be `xparse`, but I cannot try if it works correctly right now (if someone checks and it doesn't work I will remove it).

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand\integral{ m m e{_^} }{\integralaux{#1}{#2}#3}
\NewDocumentCommand\integralaux{mmmm}
 {\int\IfValueT{#3}{_{#3}}\IfValueT{#4}{^{#4}}%
  \mathopen{}#1\mathclose{}\mathop{}\!d#2\mathclose{}}
```

With this second version, you can use with flexibility `\integral{x}{x}`, `\integral{x}{x}_{a}`, `\integral{x}{x}^{a}`, `\integral{x}{x}_{a}^{b}`, `\integral{x}{x}^{a}_{b}`.

Also, it's possible to do it with `\@ifnextchar` and classical LaTeX, and has already been done in this site.

Answer (score 2):

You might do something like this, but note the name I gave to the new command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse,relsize}

\NewDocumentCommand{\badint}{e{_^}}{%
  \mathop{
    \mathchoice
      {\displaystyle\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\int_{\mathsmaller{\mathsmaller{#1}}}^{\mathsmaller{\mathsmaller{#2}}}}}}
      {\textstyle\mathlarger{\int_{\mathsmaller{#1}}^{\mathsmaller{#2}}}}
      {\scriptstyle\mathlarger{\int_{\mathsmaller{#1}}^{\mathsmaller{#2}}}}
      {\scriptscriptstyle\mathlarger{\int_{\mathsmaller{#1}}^{\mathsmaller{#2}}}}
  }
}

\begin{document}
\[
\badint_0^1 f(x)\,dx \ne \int_0^1 f(x)\,dx
\qquad
\textstyle
\badint_0^1 f(x)\,dx \ne \int_0^1 f(x)\,dx
\]

\end{document}
```

I find the output really ugly.

[image]