# How do you make an arbitrary capital Greek letter behave like the \sum command?

Tags: symbols

My question is simple. I'm using a rarely used operation which requires a rarely used Greek symbol to represent it. My current way of writing it when written out in basic LaTex looks like

```
$$\Omega_{j=0}^\infty \phi_j$$
```

Which attaches the `\{j = 0\}` part to the *lower right* and the `{\infty}` to the *upper right* of the Greek symbol \Omega.

My trouble is simple. I want it to look like how it looks when we type

```
$$\sum_{j=0}^\infty \phi_j$$
```

Except with the capital Sigma replaced with a capital Omega.

That is, I want the `{j=0}` to appear directly below the `\Omega` and the `{\infty}` to appear directly above the `\Omega`. I also want the `\Omega` to appear as largely as the `\Sigma` appears in `$$\sum$$`.

Is this possible?

Disclaimer: I've never posted here before so I'm wary of the format of my question; I'm not sure if this matches the guidelines. I'm happy to edit if necessary.

Comment: Try `\DeclareMathOperator*{\OmSum}{\Omega}` and load `amsmath` before.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that! I hope my question wasn't too trivial!

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116506/how-are-big-operators-defined