# How to create a new math operator?

Tags: symbols, math-operators

How can I create my own scalable math operator with limits just like the sum symbol? Specifically I want to invent a "concatenation" symbol that looks alike to: "[". For example I want to put

```
[ _{i=1}^N
```

etc. where the subscript/superscripts are positioned below and above the symbol as in "eqnarray" environment.

I have tried with `\newcommand` and creating a drawing similar to "[" with `\begin{picture} \end{picture}`, but it didn't work.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Something like `$\mathop{\Big[}\limits_{i=1}^N$`?

Comment: Welcome! If you post a very small code with what you tried, it would be great: people here could find what's wrong without having to guess too much. So please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) even if it doesn't really work

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116506/how-are-big-operators-defined

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes, after posting my answer, I realize this is essentially the same thing you did in your linked solution. Would you like to post it as an answer? I can remove mine.

Comment: Thank you   @SandyG ,@StevenB.Segletes , @Jairo}

Comment: @SandyG Your answer is fine (+1)

Comment: It may seem strange, but we typically don't thank contributors in the comments. Instead we show thanks by [upvoting any useful answers and accepting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) the one we find most helpful. Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 40):

A simple solution would be to use the `\DeclareMathOperator*` command from the `amsmath` package. The unstarred version places sub- and superscript limits to the right of the operator; the starred version places limits above and below the operator when it is in displaystyle.

`\DeclareMathOperator*{\concat}{[}` will produce the following results:

[image]

You could leave it like that, but for me, the displayed version produces a `[` symbol that is too small. Using the `scalerel` package, you could make the symbol the same size as a `\sum` symbol:

`\DeclareMathOperator*{\concat}{\scalerel*{[}{\sum}}`, which will produce the following:
[image]

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,scalerel}

%\DeclareMathOperator*{\concat}{[}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\concat}{\scalerel*{[}{\sum}}

\begin{document}

\[
\concat_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n
\]

Inline: $\concat_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 17):

You can use a modified version of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23436/4427 (first code set).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\bigop[2][1]{%
  \mathop{\vphantom{\sum}\mathpalette\bigop@{{#2}{#1}}}\slimits@
}
\newcommand{\bigop@}[2]{\bigop@@#1#2}
\newcommand{\bigop@@}[3]{%
  \vcenter{%
    \sbox\z@{$#1\sum$}%
    \hbox{\resizebox{#3\dimexpr\ifx#1\displaystyle.9\fi\dimexpr\ht\z@+\dp\z@}{!}{$\m@th#2$}}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\bigconcat}{\DOTSB\bigop[0.5]{[\,}}

\begin{document}
\[
\sum_{i=1}^n \bigconcat_{i=1}^n x_i
\qquad
\textstyle
\sum\bigconcat_{i=1}^n x_i
\qquad
\scriptstyle
\sum\bigconcat_{i=1}^n x_i
\qquad
\scriptscriptstyle
\sum\bigconcat_{i=1}^n x_i
\]
\end{document}
```

The scaling is necessary because of how TeX is treating `[`.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

My idea uses `\left[\phantom{\sum}\right.` trick:

```
\def\concat{\mathop{\left[\vphantom{\sum}\right.}}

Test:
$\concat_{n=1}^\infty 
 \displaystyle \concat_{n=1}^\infty
 \scriptstyle \concat_{n=1}^\infty
$

\bye
```