# How to create product operator for arbitrary binary operator

Tags: math-mode, math-operators, displaystyle

I have defined a couple of different mathmode binary operators in my paper, but I realized I need to apply them to arbitrary finite sets of objects. Is there a standard way to make a related product-like operator, which is bigger and has displaystyle limits by default? I want the new operator to have the same relationship to the old one that `\bigoplus` has to `\oplus`.

Ideally, I am looking for a way to define a command like `\bigbin{}` which takes a hypothetical binary operator `\newtimes` in the argument and produces a product version. So `\bigbin{\newtimes}` would look the same as `\newtimes`, but it would be bigger, and have display-style limits. Failing that, I would like to know both how to make an arbitrary glyph bigger, and what it is that makes the product operator special, besides display style limits—i.e. how to make my own `\bignewtimes` command looks like a bigger `\newtimes` but acts like a product operator.

Comment: Does [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/573860/125871) answer your question?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this answers my second question—thanks for the pointer. I still have to study it a bit to understand how it works lol. And to be honest I believe my first question is out of reach

Comment: Maybe not. I think `\DeclareMathOperator*` together with the `scalerel` package can do what you want.