# Symbol for concatenation of more than two strings

Tags: symbols

To define string concatenation, I use the || symbol to concatenate two strings, like `S1||S2`. Now I need to show the concatenation of more than two. Is there any known symbol to define the concatenation of more than two strings, like the sum in `\sum_{i=1}^N S_i`, but with something different from `\sum`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I think your question is off topic here. Better ask on a mathematican forum...

Comment: I think the question is on topic. It is asked for how to produce a big operator from two vertical bars, as I understand it. Maybe [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/394901/52406) (or its answers) could be helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I type a vector concatenation symbol like this one?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/636239/how-do-i-type-a-vector-concatenation-symbol-like-this-one)

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using `\DeclareMathOperator*` and the `scalerel` package:

[image]

In the code below, `\scalerel*` scales the `\Vert` symbol (double vertical lines) to match the size of a `\sum` symbol, whether inline or displayed or in a subscript. `\DeclareMathOperator` gives the symbol the same behavior as a large operator like `\sum`. The starred version `\DeclareMathOperator*` places the limits above and below when displayed, but on the right when inline.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,scalerel}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\concat}{\scalerel*{\Vert}{\sum}}

\begin{document}

Inline: $\concat_{n=1}^{\infty} S_n$. Display: $\displaystyle{\concat_{n=1}^{\infty} S_n}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could consider adding `For 2 arguments: ${S_1}\concat{S_2}$.` to illustrate the nice spacing of this approach even as an operator between 2 arguments (like `+`)

Comment: I was also tinkering with `\&` as the operator, instead of `\Vert`, but the scaling gets wonky. Some people may find this hack useful: replace `\Vert` with `\vphantom{\textstyle\sum}\smash{\&}` to get better scaling with that approach.

Comment: @Sandy G Thanks, this is exactly what I tried as the first thought. I was principally interested if such an operator exists and is commonly used (somehow, I do not know myself). Anyway, many thanks!
Sorry, as a new member, I cannot upvote. ):-