# How to modify \forall so that it places sub/superscripts below/above just like \sum?

Tags: math-operators

How to modify \forall so that it places sub/superscripts below/above the "all" symbol? Just like \sum or \int.

Comment: You can use `\mathop` (and `\limits` if needed).

Comment: @caboha No, the top solution https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/573860/34503, with "\forall" substituted for "[", does not work.

Comment: "does not work" is not a helpful statement.  Please post the code you tried, and if necessary explain what went wrong.

Comment: Don't read only “the top solution”. Already [the first comment to that question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/573850/how-to-create-a-new-math-operator/573860#comment1445376_573850) using `\forall` instead of `\Big[` would work.

Comment: Indeed, with `\mathop{\forall}\limits` I get the right placement though the "all" symbol is way too small.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want? Taken from my solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/573860/125871). The `\scalerel*` command sizes the `\forall` symbol to match the size of a `\sum` symbol. Note that `\DeclareMathOperator*` requires the `amsmath` package and `\scalerel*` requires the `scalerel` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,scalerel}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\Forall}{\scalerel*{\forall}{\sum}}

\begin{document}

\[
\Forall_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n
\]

Inline: $\Forall_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I am using plain latex;dvips;ps2pdf under a document class provided by a publisher (IUCr). Only sub- and superscript are shown, but not the "all" symbol. There is no empty box; the sub/superscript placement indicates that instead of the symbol there is at most a box of size 0.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to kind input from @cabohah, here a solution that is not perfect but looks well enough:

```
\def\Forall{\mathop{\raisebox{-5pt}{\scalebox{2.0}{\ensuremath \forall}}}\limits}
```

Not perfect because the numeric constants need to be adjusted for given font size.