# vertical alignment of custom symbol

Tags: symbols, vertical-alignment, raise

I defined the following command

```
\newcommand{\bigast}{\mathop{\Huge \mathlarger{\mathlarger{*}}}}
```

Unfortunately, its vertical alignment is a bit too high

[image]

I tried fixing it with \raisebox{} but couldn't make it work. Any ideas how to correct its vertical alignment?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: At the very least this code will give a warning about `\Huge` being invalid in math mode. Please post a complete code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [How are big operators defined?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116506/how-are-big-operators-defined/116538#116538), this makes the `\ast` occupy the same vertical footprint as `\sum`, which we know is well behaved.

I show two implementations, one that retains the `\textstyle` size always, and the other that grows in `\displaystyle`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\foo}{\scalerel*{\ast}{\sum}}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\barr}{\scalerel*{\ast}{\textstyle\sum}}
\usepackage{scalerel}

\begin{document}
\[
\foo_{i=3}^{6}(f^2(i))
\]

This is inline: \(\foo_{i=3}^{6}(f^2(i)) \)

\[
\barr_{i=3}^{6}(f^2(i))
\]

This is inline: \(\barr_{i=3}^{6}(f^2(i)) \)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: that's just wonderful. thank you so much!