# Custom limit locations

Tags: math-operators, subscripts, superscripts, displaystyle, customize

[How are big operators defined?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116506/how-are-big-operators-defined/116538#116538)

Starting with something like the above, I want to place the lower limit in a displaymath-size symbol below it and the upper limit to the right side (essentially middle right). Is there any way to do this easily? Obviously I'd like a way to sort of customize the point it uses, say upper left for where it decides to put the limit.

Comment: I don't really understand the problem. Could you attach a picture (even hand-drawn) of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Most math symbols have 4 sizes, corresponding to \displayatyle, \textstyle, \scriptstyle and \scriptscriptstyle.  Others (the ones that use \left and \right) are more complicated.

Comment: Probably OP have the same question as [positioning - How does a math operator specify the horizontal position of its limits? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/667287/how-does-a-math-operator-specify-the-horizontal-position-of-its-limits).