# Creating a product integration symbol which behaves as the standard integration symbol

Tags: math-mode, symbols, math-operators

**Context**. The *product integral* is the continuous analogue of the ordinary (Riemann, Lebesgue, Denjoy, Perron etc...) integral and was introduced by Vito Volterra in 1887 in order to provide a compact functional way to express the solution to the Cauchy problem for systems of ordinary differential equations. The interested reader can have a look to [this book by Antonín Slavík, *Product integration, its history and applications*, Matfyzpress 2007](https://www2.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/%7Eprusv/ncmm/notes/download/product_integration.pdf). 
In the ordinary practice (also in the reference cited above), the product integral is represented as the ordinary "uppercase `\Pi`" by the standard command `\prod` in a fashion similar to what one obtains by using the code

```
\prod_0^t (1+r(s))^{\operatorname{d}s}
```

Nevertheless, from the logical and clarity viewpoint this is somewhat unsatisfactory: *why should we use the same symbol for the product of finite or infinite discrete terms even for the product of infinite "infinitesimal" terms?*
 For the ordinary integral we know that this limit operation leads from the summation symbol `\sum` to the `\int` symbol, is a sort of script-style uppercase "S".

**The problem to be solved**. My idea is to define a `\pint` command which prints a sort of script-style uppercase "P" and behaves exactly as the `\int` symbol. Precisely

1. `\pint` should be the standard command,
2. the expression following the command should be graphically centred respect to the height of the symbol (as it happens for the standard `\int` symbol),
3. `\pint\limits` should be the command use to put the product integration limits above and below the `\pint` symbol,
4. the script-style "P" could be made by using something like `\mathscr{P}` or by using an .svg or other vector kind of image obtained by modifying the standard `\int` symbol.

**Some experiments aimed at obtaining the sought-for graphical result**. I've managed to produce something of this sort by using the following preamble code declarations

```
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{stix}
\newcommand{\dm}{\mathrm{d}}
```

Then, in order to obtain a "standard style" `\pint` I defined the following command

```
% Definition of Volterra's product integral, standard style.
\DeclareMathOperator{\pint}{{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathscr{P}}}}}}}
```

which, invoked in the body of the document as `\pint_{\!\!\!\!\!\!0}^{t}(1+r(s))^{\dm s}`, produces the following graphical output:
[image]

After that, in order to obtain an `\int\limits` flavour command I defined the following

```
% Definition of Volterra's product integral, \limits style.
\DeclareMathOperator*{\pint}{{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathscr{P}}}}}}}
```

which, invoked in the body of the document as `\pint_{\!\!\!\!\!\!0}^{\quad t}(1+r(s))^{\dm s}`, produces the following graphical output:
[image]

While the graphical flavour obtained is similar to the one desired, the solutions presented are somewhat unsatisfactory respect to the first tree of the above points, i.e.

1. invoking the `\pint` command is not sufficient in order to have the subscripts and superscripts correctly placed, since you have to tweak their position by "bare hands", and
2. the expression **is not graphically centred** respect to the `\pint` symbol, and finally
3. in oder to obtain the `\pint\limits` behaviour I have to completely redefine the command.

Comment: Welcome to the TeX. SE. community :-). Ciao.

Comment: Ciao @Sebastiano. Happy new year.

Comment: What about a `\Pi` symbol upon the `\int` one?

Comment: @projetmbc it may be interesting. Could you elaborate an answer or give a reference?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's my proposal

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx,mathrsfs}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\pint}{t\limits e{_^}}{%
  \DOTSI\pint@{#1}{#2}{#3}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\pint@}{mmm}{%
  \mathop{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\pint@limits}{\pint@nolimits}{#2}{#3}%
  }%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\pint@limits}{mm}{%
  \mathpalette\pint@@limits{{#1}{#2}}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\pint@@limits}{mm}{%
  \pint@@@limits#1#2%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\pint@@@limits}{mmm}{%
  \mathop{\vcenter{
    \sbox\z@{\raisebox{\depth}{$\m@th#1\int$}}%
    \hbox{\resizebox{!}{0.95\ht\z@}{$\m@th\mathscr{P}$}\vphantom{\box\z@}}%
  }}\limits\IfValueT{#2}{_{#2}}\IfValueT{#3}{^{\mspace{\if@display18\else9\fi mu}#3}}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\pint@nolimits}{mm}{%
  \mathpalette\pint@@nolimits{{#1}{#2}}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\pint@@nolimits}{mm}{%
  \pint@@@nolimits#1#2%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\pint@@@nolimits}{mmm}{%
  \vcenter{
    \sbox\z@{\raisebox{\depth}{$\m@th#1\int$}}%
    \hbox{\resizebox{!}{0.95\ht\z@}{$\m@th\mathscr{P}$}\vphantom{\box\z@}}%
  }\IfValueT{#2}{_{\mspace{-\if@display24\else12\fi mu}#2}}\IfValueT{#3}{^{#3}}%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\pint_a^b \int_a^b \pint\limits_a^b \int\limits_a^b
\]
\begin{center}
$\pint_a^b \int_a^b \pint\limits_a^b \int\limits_a^b$
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like to mention the `prodint` package. With a little twist, though.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{prodint}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\pint{\DOTSI\if@display\PRODI\else\prodi\fi\ilimits@}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\pint_a^b \int_a^b \pint\limits_a^b \int\limits_a^b
\]
\begin{center}
$\pint_a^b \int_a^b \pint\limits_a^b \int\limits_a^b$
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried your first solution and it worked perfectly in my document. One last supplementary question: if I want to use a custom drawn symbol instead of $\mathscr{P}$, is it simply sufficient to insert its import command instead of the character one?

Comment: @DanieleTampieri Maybe. It depends on what you're trying to insert.

Comment: maybe an .svg picture produced by generating the `\int` symbol in an Inkscape sheet and then modifying it in order to resemble a stylized pi.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri You need to try. Actually, there's space for improvement in the code. Keep testing.

Answer (score 10):

A direct adaptation of my answer at [How are big operators defined?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116506/how-are-big-operators-defined/116538#116538).  Here, `\foo` gives a larger symbol in `\displaystyle`, as does `\int`, whereas `\barr` retains the size of the symbol associated with `\textstyle`, even in display math.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\foo}{\scalerel*{\mathscr{P}}{\sum}}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\barr}{\scalerel*{\mathscr{P}}{\textstyle\sum}}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{scalerel}

\begin{document}
\[
\foo_{i=3}^{6}(f^2(i))
\]

This is inline: \(\foo_{i=3}^{6}(f^2(i)) \)

\[
\barr_{i=3}^{6}(f^2(i))
\]

This is inline: \(\barr_{i=3}^{6}(f^2(i)) \)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Mico notes that `\barr` should not be used in either of the script styles, which is true.  If that usage were to be necessary, then `\barr` could instead be defined as

```
\DeclareMathOperator*{\barr}{\scalerel*{\mathscr{P}}{\mathchoice
  {\textstyle\sum}{\sum}{\sum}{\sum}}}
```

In the above MWE, the "P" is scaled to the same size as `\sum`.  If you would prefer it scaled to the size of `\int`, just replace `\sum` with `\int` in each of the `\DeclareMathOperator`s and the result looks like:

[image]

Comment: +1. You may want to add an explicit warning that `\barr` shouldn't be used in `\scriptstyle`, let alone `\scriptscriptstyle`, surroundings. Of course, this caveat should be obvious for anyone who actually looks at the code.

Comment: +1 Steven. Your approach fulfills requirements 1 and 2 and at least seems capable to fulfill requirement 3. I'll wait a bit but, if there aren't other answers I'll accept your as the answer. Thank you very much

Comment: Just out of idle curiosity: Would there be anything wrong with defining `\barr` via `\DeclareMathOperator*{\barr}{{\textstyle\foo}}`?

Comment: @Mico While it may work, I would not recommend it, from an efficiency point of view.  It would be nesting `\mathop`s and worse still, nesting `\scalerel`s.

Comment: @Mico As to the warning, I have added one, as well as a workaround.  See my edit.

Answer (score 2):

Imo, the functional (single letter) notation for the integral is simple and more economical than the integral symbol, it can explicitly show (instead of hiding it in often unused `dx`) the integrating variable if needed,  and it doesn't depend on the dimension.  The notation also needs to be easily usable when writing in class on a board.  So a simple `\DeclareMathOperator*{\pint}{\mathbf{P}}` should do the job, but in the example, below a font is used with a longer neck for distinction, and it still can be easily replicated in handwriting.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{scalerel}

% for longer neck letters but don't use them by default
\usepackage[nodefault,typeone]{drm}

% 
\newcommand{\drm}[1]{{\fontfamily{drm}\selectfont #1}}

% Longer neck P
\DeclareMathOperator*{\pint}{\textrm{\drm{P}}}

% Longer neck P large operator
\DeclareMathOperator*{\Pint}{\scalerel*{\textrm{\drm{P}}}{\int}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
  $\pint_a^b(1+r(s))$
  & $\displaystyle \pint_a^b(1+r(s))$\\[1cm]
  $\pint_{s \in [a,b]}(1+r(s))$
  & $\displaystyle \pint_{s \in [a,b]}(1+r(s))$\\[1cm]
  $\pint_{(s,t) \in [a,b]\times[c,d]}(1+r(s,t))$
  & $\displaystyle \pint_{(s,t) \in [a,b]\times[c,d]}(1+r(s,t))$\\[1cm]
  $\pint_{s^2+t^2=1}(1+r(s,t))$
  & $\displaystyle \pint_{s^2+t^2=1}(1+r(s,t))$\\[1cm]
  $\Pint_{s^2+t^2=1}(1+r(s,t))$
  & $\displaystyle \Pint_{s^2+t^2=1}(1+r(s,t))$
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Product integral symbol]

Comment: Btw, Computer Modern Dunhill `cmdh` (https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/computermoderndunhillroman/) is available if one wishes to have a computer modern matching uppercase P with a longer neck.

Comment: For this purpose, you are right, @ApoorvPotnis, `cmdh` or `lmdh` would be better.  They do not have bold face versions, while that's what I use in my papers for some single letter operators.