# Large Blackboard bold R operator with text underneath

Tags: math-operators, blackboard

How do I typeset a large blackboard bold R (size of a \sum symbol) as an operator in an equation? See image.
I can get the text to display underneath with \mathop{}, but I can't make the R big. \displaystyle doesn't make the symbol any bigger.[image: hand-written notes]

I can get a solution of sorts in XeLaTeX, but I would prefer a LaTeX solution.

This is the XeLaTeX solution

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix}_{\substack{\text{some text}\\\text{other text}}}
= 
\sum_x\mathop{\text{\huge ℝ}}_{\text{sys1}\rightarrow\text{sys2}}
\begin{bmatrix} X \\ Y \\ Z \end{bmatrix}_{\substack{\text{more text}\\\text{also text}}}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, I've copy-pasted the unicode character and made it \huge, and used \mathop to put the text underneath. It's not an elegant solution, it's not very portable since it depends on the text font instead of a math font and it doesn't center the R on the '=' properly (compare the sum).*[image: example xelatex solution]*

What is a better way to do this? Preferably in LaTeX.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. According to [Defining a different symbol to be used as a sum-class symbol](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116355/defining-a-different-symbol-to-be-used-as-a-sum-class-symbol/116361#116361), you need `\DeclareMathOperator{\bigR}{\text{\Large{$\mathbb{R}$}}}`

Comment: related: [How to create my own math operator with limits?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23436/579)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This does the job nicely I think (thanks **karlkoeller** for suggesting improvements):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,relsize,graphicx,dsfont}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\smallR{\mathds{R}} % <-- this is your symbol
\newcommand*\yo@bigR[2]{\text{#2\raisebox{-#1ex}{$\smallR$}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\bigR{\mathop{\mathchoice
  {\yo@bigR{0.5}{\larger\larger\larger\larger}} % displaystyle
  {\yo@bigR{0.4}{\larger\larger}} % textstyle
  {\yo@bigR{0.3}{\larger\larger}} % scriptstyle
  {\text{\scalebox{1.4}{\raisebox{-0.3ex}{$\smallR$}}}} % scriptscriptstyle
  }\displaylimits}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix}_{\substack{\text{some text}\\\text{other text}}}
= 
\sum_x\bigR_{\text{sys1}\rightarrow\text{sys2}}
\begin{bmatrix} X \\ Y \\ Z \end{bmatrix}_{\substack{\text{more text}\\\text{also text}}}
\end{equation*}

\centering

\section{In section title $\sum_x\bigR_{\text{sys1}\rightarrow\text{sys2}}$}

Textstyle: \qquad $\sum_x\bigR_{\text{sys1}\rightarrow\text{sys2}}$

Scriptstyle: \qquad $\scriptstyle
\sum_x\bigR_{\text{sys1}\rightarrow\text{sys2}}$

Scriptscriptstyle: \quad $\scriptscriptstyle
\sum_x\bigR_{\text{sys1}\rightarrow\text{sys2}}$

\end{document}
```

It would somehow work by just using:

```
\newcommand\bigR{\mathop{\text{\LARGE\raisebox{-0.5ex}{$\mathds{R}$}}}\limits}
```

The rest of the mess above is to make it work in any environment and possibly in any font size.

Comment: Yes, much better. Add also a possibility with `\mathds` which it seems to match better with the OP's symbol.

Answer (score 8):

This will produce symbols with the same vertical size as `\sum` in any style and with any font size; any math alphabet can be used.

For a commonly used symbol, define a specific command, as I did for `\Rop`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx,amssymb}
\usepackage{dsfont} % for the example


\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\letterop}[1]{\mathop{\mathpalette\letterop@do{#1}}}
\newcommand\letterop@do[2]{%
  \vcenter{%
    \sbox{\z@}{$\m@th#1\sum$}%
    \dimen@=\ht\z@ \advance\dimen@\dp\z@
    \sbox{\z@}{$\m@th#1#2$}\dp\z@=\z@ % kill the depth
    \hbox{\resizebox{!}{\dimen@}{\unhbox\z@}}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\Rop}{\letterop{\mathds{R}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix}_{\substack{\text{some text}\\\text{other text}}}
= 
\sum_x\Rop_{\text{sys1}\rightarrow\text{sys2}}
\begin{bmatrix} X \\ Y \\ Z \end{bmatrix}_{\substack{\text{more text}\\\text{also text}}}
\end{equation*}

\section{In section title $\sum_x\Rop_{\text{sys1}\rightarrow\text{sys2}}$}

Textstyle: \qquad $\sum_x\Rop_{\text{sys1}\rightarrow\text{sys2}}$

Scriptstyle: \qquad $\scriptstyle
\sum_x\Rop_{\text{sys1}\rightarrow\text{sys2}}$

Scriptscriptstyle: \quad $\scriptscriptstyle
\sum_x\Rop_{\text{sys1}\rightarrow\text{sys2}}$

\[ \letterop{\mathrm{S}}_{i=1}^n \letterop{\mathbb{R}}_{i=1}^n \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
\newcommand*{\Scale}[2][4]{\scalebox{#1}{$#2$}}%
\newcommand*{\Resize}[2]{\resizebox{#1}{!}{$#2$}}%

\newcommand{\MathOp}[5]{\displaystyle{\mathop{\Scale[#1]{#2}}_{#3}^{#4}#5}}
```

and thy with

```
\MathOp{1.5}{\mathbb R}{pedex}{apex}{something}
```

Good by