# Sum-class personalised operators

Tags: math-operators

Following Bourbaki, Algebra, I wanted to describe the 'composition of an ordered sequence' of elements of a magma with an operation that is neither `+` nor `\cdot` so with a different big operator like `\sum`. Herewith a scan of the bit. Please ignore the fact that it is in line: what I wish to have should be acting like `\sum`.

[image: Bourbaki, Algebra]

I have seen [this similar post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116355/defining-a-different-symbol-to-be-used-as-a-sum-class-symbol) and [this other post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5042/define-strange-operators) but neither respond precisely to my problem.

1. I wish I could have a command like `\bigop[1]` in which I can choose the symbol wanted (e.g. Bourbaki would use `\bigop{\top}` and `\bigop{\bot}`.
2. The symbol should be vertically centred, like `\sum` and `\prod` are.

I have tried the following, but it seems to me it is a not particularly elegant solution. I hope someone has a much more elegant one.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\newcommand{\bigop}[1]{\mathop{\raisebox{-3pt}{$#1$}}

\begin{document}
\[
\bigop{*}_{a \in A} x_a
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/306556/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23432/35864 (and linked questions) may be useful.